# Making Divs the same height not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to make two div's inside a container div have the same height.  I'm using bootstrap's grid.  As you can see in the image example below.  The output shows the div with the class `page-member-detail-info` (the green border div) not taking up 100% of it's parent div's height.

**NOTE:  If I make the height of the div with the class `page-member-detail-container` (the red border div) a fixed value like 250px.  Then the result is as expected. The `page-member-detail-info` (the green border div) will be 100% of the height.**

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 page-member-detail-container">
            <div class="col-sm-3 page-member-detail-image">
                <img src="http://example.com/image.jpg" alt="My Image">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9 page-member-detail-info">
                DETAILS
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.page-member-detail-container {
    border: 3px solid #FF0000; // red
    padding: 0;
}

.page-member-detail-image {
    border: 3px solid #0000ff; // blue
    padding-left: 0;
}

.page-member-detail-image>img {
    width: 100%;
}

.page-member-detail-info {
    border: 3px solid #009b00; // green
    height: 100%;
}
```

[image: example output]

Comment: if Flexbox doesn't work for you, you should try the plugin [matchHeights](https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height). It solves the exact problem you are facing and you do not need to write any javascript. Just include the attribute `data-mh="group_name"` on all elements you want to match heights (the bootstrap `col-`'s in your case) no matter the content (where "group_name" is a string you assign). I have had a lot of success with this plugin

Answer (score 2):

Another case for Flexbox!  Simply add display:flex to your container.

```css
.page-member-detail-container {
    border: 3px solid #FF0000;
    padding: 0;  
    display: flex;
}

.page-member-detail-image {
    border: 3px solid #0000ff;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.page-member-detail-image>img {
    width: 100%;
}

.page-member-detail-info {
    border: 3px solid #009b00;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 page-member-detail-container">
            <div class="col-sm-3 page-member-detail-image">
                <img src="http://example.com/image.jpg" alt="My Image">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9 page-member-detail-info">
                DETAILS
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If supporting older browsers is a concern, then you can set . page-member-detail-container to display:table and child DIVs to display:table-cell. This will give you the equal heights you are looking for. Also, it opens up the vertical-align property as well.